# "invalid continuation byte" Python Socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Im a Amateur and i got a Problem with my Socket. 
With the program I want to access another computer via a socket and download files.
I tried to solve it myself but I can't do it. I even looked at several forums and found no solution.

Thank you for any help! I really enjoy learning new things.

Here is the Code:

Server:

```
import socket

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind(("", 4444))
socket.listen(1)
client, addr = socket.accept()


def navigate():
    while True:
        directory = client.recv(1024).decode()
        global chose
        chose = input(directory + " $:")
        if chose.startswith("download"):
            download()
        if chose.startswith("cd"):
            client.send(bytes(chose, "utf-8"))
            files = client.recv(5000).decode()
            print("\n" + "Files:\n" + files + "\n")


def download():
    splitted_chose = chose[9:]
    client.send(bytes(chose, "utf-8"))
    bytes_len = client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    data = client.recv(int(bytes_len))
    with open("Downloads/" + splitted_chose, "wb") as file:
        file.write(data)
        print(str(splitted_chose) + " downloaded!\n")
        file.close()


navigate()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import os

ip = "192.168.178.62"
port = 4444

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((ip, port))

while True:
    directory = os.getcwd()
    socket.send(bytes(directory, "utf-8"))
    command = socket.recv(1024).decode()

    if command.startswith("cd"):
        splitted_input = command.split(" ")
        os.chdir(splitted_input[1])
        files = os.listdir()
        string_files = ""
        for file in files:
            string_files += file + ", "
        socket.send(bytes(string_files, "utf-8"))

    if command.startswith("download"):
        splitted_command = command[9:]
        path = directory + "/" + splitted_command
        bytes_len = os.path.getsize(path)
        bytes_len_str = str(bytes_len)
        socket.send(bytes(bytes_len_str, "utf-8"))

        with open(path, "rb") as f:
            data = f.read()
            socket.send(data)
            f.close()
```

Console Output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jonny/PycharmProjects/Batman/Server.py", line 33, in <module>
    navigate()
  File "C:/Users/jonny/PycharmProjects/Batman/Server.py", line 15, in navigate
    download()
  File "C:/Users/jonny/PycharmProjects/Batman/Server.py", line 25, in download
    bytes_len = client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 5: invalid start byte
```